# What's safe to use as EXTRA_OUTPUT

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`  to get an image from Camera. What places is safe to use as the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` ?

The only one I've found myself is SdCard, but it seems inconvenient to me (I need a permission, and user has to have an SdCard). Is there another place, I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Activity.getCacheDir()`.